# Eclipse CDT edits displays bogus errors gcc finds none

Tags: c++, eclipse

The program works just s I expect.

I'm trying to learn to use Eclipse for C++.   I keep going back to the terminal because of stuff like this.   The program compiles and runs clem in Eclipse when I click the green arrow.  Now so much as a warning message.   But as you see the editor is clutters with bogus errors.  The console output is as you'd expect.

This is on Mac OS X using the GCC that is included with Xcode.   How to correct this problem.  Maybe the editor and gcc have different search paths?

Here is a screen shot [enter link description here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28915695/EclispeError.jpg)

![Bogus Erros in Eclipse][2]

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you added valid paths for the additional includes (and the standard includes too).
- Make sure that the compiler (and compilation options) used from terminal is the same options used in eclipse.